# get touchJson data for int type

Tags: iphone, ios, touchjson

I am using touchJson to deserialize my json from server. My json is like below:

```
{"text":"abc", "user_id":12345}
```

After deserializing, I use below code to get the Json values:

```
NSString *text = [dict objectForKey:@"text"];
```

This is simple because the data is string, but for "user_id" what type should I use to decode, is it correct?:

```
NSInteger *user_id = [dict objectForKey:@"user_id"];
```

If not, what's the right way to hold the integer json type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TouchJSON will decode a number to `NSNumber` not `NSInteger`

```
NSNumber *user_id = [dict objectForKey:@"user_id"];
```

Comment: @BinChen same actually, still a NSNumber. To put the appropriate `NSNumber` into the dictionary you would do `NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];`, likewise when you deserialize and you have the corresponding `NSNumber` you would do `[n boolValue];`.